# How do we implement Scroll to top functionality on tapping of the corresponding tab button on a bottom tab navigator in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

The React Navigation version I am using is v5. In the ScrollView corresponding to a Bottom Tab Icon, if the user is already on that given screen, I want to enable functionality where the user scrolls to the top when this icon is pressed.

Comment: use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#tabpress), this feature should be already implemented. But I think you have placed your ScrollView inside a nested StackNavigator, right?

In that case, you probably need to subscribe to TabNavigator event and fire your scrollToTop manually

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', e => {
    // Get your scrollView ref and dispatch scrollToTop
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

Hope it'll help you!

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me on the web, not using `listener` and not using `useScrollToTop` which is provided by `react-navigation`. Because I have nested stacks and navigators and also custom tabbar.

I solved the problem by setting a navigation param for scrolling to the top.

I have custom tabbar, and I needed to scroll to top on the homepage which was the first route of the tab stack.

So, in the homepage I set the `scrollToTop` parameter for the navigator:

```
const homelistRef = React.useRef<FlatList | null>(null)

useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      navigation.setParams({
        scrollToTop: () => homelistRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0, animated: true }),
      });
    }, [navigation, homelistRef]),
  );


return (

<FlatList
    ref={homelistRef}
    ...{other Flatlist configs}
    />

)
```

And in my Tabbar component, I read this new param and execute it in the `onPress` function of the tabs:

```
interface IProps extends BottomTabBarProps {}

const TabBar: React.FC<IProps> = ({ state, navigation }) => {

const handleTabPress = useCallback(
    (route) => async () => {
      const currentRoute = state.routes?.[state.index];

      if (
        route === currentRoute?.name &&
        state.routes?.[0].state?.routes?.[0]?.params?.scrollToTop
      ) {
        state.routes[0].state.routes[0].params.scrollToTop();
      }
    },
    [navigation, state],
  );

   return (
      {render tab component}
   )
}
```

And that's the ultimate solution for executing some action on active tabs.